# Plotting multiple series generated using a for loop in python on the same figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Data=np.array(([200,99],[200,62],[200,40],[300,94],[300,44],[300,24],[400,86],[400,35],[400,13]))
X_axis=[]
Y_axis=[]
for j in range(3):
    
    Counter=j
    for i in range(3):
        X=Data[i+Counter,0]
        Y=Data[i+Counter,1]
        X_axis.append(X)
        Y_axis.append(Y)
        Counter=Counter+2
    #plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(X_axis,Y_axis, linestyle='solid', marker='o')
    plt.show()
    X_axis=[]
    Y_axis=[]
```

With this code I am getting three separate figures for three series of data set I am generating using two for loops. I am trying to plot all the three series on a single figure. The three series are:
Series-1: x-axis [200,300,400], y-axis [99,94,86]; Series-2: x-axis [200,300,400], y-axis [62,44,35]; Series-3: x-axis [200,300,400], y-axis [40,24,13] By reseting the X_axis and Y_axis inside the nested for loop, I am trying to generate three separate series, otherwise they get appended. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Move `plt.show()` out of all of the loops and see what happens

Comment: It worked! I appreciate your response.